# Working with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array

```
var arr = ["one","two","three","four"];
```

Is it possible to convert it like this through some regexes

```
"one","two","three","four"
```

the resultant should not be an entire string rather it is comma separated strings.

Any suggestions ???

Comment: What do you mean you want it to be comma separated strings?

Comment: You need some thing like `"one","two","three","four"` or `"one,two,three, four"`

Comment: my result should be "one","two","three","four"

Comment: And where do you need this? I am asking because a) there may be better ways if we know the whole picture and b) you may or may not need to handle nested quotes or commas

Comment: @SelvaGanesh yes you said that already but it doesn't mean anything. It's very admirable that people are trying to provide you with an answer but they are just stabbing at the darkness in the hope that they'll hit something. Comma separated strings is not a javascript data type that I am aware of. So I ask you again: what do you mean comma separated strings?

Answer (score 3):

> `function func(){`
>      `var arr = ["one","two","three","four"];`
>      `var result = "";`
>      `for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {`
>             `result += '"' + arr[i] + '",';`
>      `}`
>      `result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);`
>      `alert(result);`
>   `}`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert this to comma-separated strings, only converting to an entire string is possible.

Use `join()` for that:

```
var result = "\"" + array.join("\",\"") + "\"";
```

Comment: If you join like that, the first and last parts will look weird.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that.

Comment: I cannot confirm that. In which way it looks "weird"? See http://jsfiddle.net/pXmex/.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to convert the array into a String.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=fruits;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three","four"];
var str = '"' + arr.join('","') + '"';
console.log(str);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYG7c/).

Answer (score -1):

In the for loop you can do anything you want with the values seperately.

```
var arr = ["one","two","three","four"];
for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```